# Unity Network Manager overriding OnServerAddPlayer doesnt apply changes to player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

In my game, I allow players to change colors in the scene. They can run over a little paint splatter, and it will change their color.

I am working on my custom [NetworkManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetManager.html) right now I need to save the changes made to the player's color every time, so that when I change scenes it will be applied.

To do this, I have written an override of the `OnServerAddPlayer` function, like stated in the Unity docs above.

The changes that I am making are not being applied to the player at all though! I have the information debugging to the console, and I know that the `NetworkManager` has the data that it needs because the colors it is storing are correct.

I have this data stored in a dictionary field of the `NetworkManager`:

```
private Dictionary<int, PlayerDataStruct> _playerData;
```

The `PlayerDataStruct` is a simple struct that each player has that stores things like `Color`, input ID, etc.

Here is my `OnServerAddPlayer` function:

```
public override void OnServerAddPlayer(NetworkConnection conn, short 
playerControllerId)
{
    Transform spawn = GetStartPosition();

    var player = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(playerPrefab, spawn.position, Quaternion.identity);


    PlayerDataStruct data = player.GetComponent<PlayerData>().data;

    Debug.Log("[NetworkManager] Connected ID: " + conn.connectionId.ToString());

    // Add this info to the dictionary 
    if(_playerData.ContainsKey(conn.connectionId))
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("[NetworkManager] ALREADY HAS THIS DATA IN IT ID:: " + conn.connectionId.ToString());

        data = _playerData[conn.connectionId];
    }
    else
    {
        _playerData.Add(conn.connectionId, data);
    }

    Debug.Log("[NetworkManager] Set ID: " + conn.connectionId.ToString() 
        + " color is " + data.PlayerColor.ToString());

    NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection(conn, player, playerControllerId);

}
```

Like I said above, the debug information that I get when I change scenes *is correct*. If A player chooses green, the console debugs green, but the spawned player will still be the default color.

Comment: You can't serialize dictionary in Unity. That's probably the source of your issue

Comment: By using [this technique](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.html) I can see that the data is there in the network manager between scenes.

Are you saying it is the problem because the data is not being serialized over the network? And if so wouldn't I get an error about that?

Comment: I suspect but I am not entirely sure. Why not try another datatype and see if it works or not

Comment: Hmm... I think you may be partially correct. I am getting some very weird behavior. My `PlayerDataStruct` is marked as `[System.Serializable]` in its definition though.